# Python Paramiko : AttributeError: 'EntryPoint' object has no attribute 'resolve'

Tags: python-2.7, paramiko

```
ssh = client.SSHClient()

paramiko. util. log_to_file ( 'paramiko.log ') 

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect(server,port=22, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False)
```

Executing this script shows below error message

> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko-2.0.1-py2.7.egg\paramiko\client.p
>   y", line 338, in connect
>       t.start_client()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko-2.0.1-py2.7.egg\paramiko\transpor
>   t.py", line 493, in start_client
>       raise e AttributeError: 'EntryPoint' object has no attribute 'resolve'

Please advice how can i solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem , downgraded cryptography to an older version 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cryptography/1.2.1#downloads

Comment: This was occurred with Python-3.4 + cryptography-1.5 when I ran testinfra that uses paramiko as the SSH backend. The error disappeared if I downgraded cryptography to 1.4.